# how to implement solr index partitioning

Tags: solr, indexing, partitioning

I want solr to create indexes based on a specific field. For e.g. I have a field in schema.xml, createDate (which might be of value 2012/2013/etc). Now while indexing if the value of that specific field is 2013, the document should be indexed at /data/2013/index folder (or some logically separated folder). I tried to provide the following in my solrconfig xml just before the `<config>` tag ends:

```
<partition>
     <partitionField name="creationYear">
      <value>2004</value>     
      <value>2005</value>     
      <value>2006</value>
      <value>2007</value>
      <value>2008</value>
      <value>2009</value>
      <value>2010</value>
      <value>2011</value>
      <value>2012</value>
      <value>2013</value>
     </partitionField>
   </partition>
```

While indexing its not working and it seems that this was just an idea but not really implemented in solr. Am I assuming correct? Or is there a way I can allow solr to create dynamic index folders based on the year(as in this example)?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I've never seen `partition` as s config-option although it may be possible it slipped me. Anyhow, not sure why you would want this: i.e: to have an index on a particular field (with the purpose of querying quickly on that field) is possible by solr without you having to worry about how documents are stored on disk, etc.

Comment: Our application has a lot of data starting from the year 2001 and each year the count is approximately around 10 million. Hence we usually move them to warehouse tables after the year completion. We want to do something similar using SOLR, after year end, all the indexes should be moved to a different directory but then the year field should also be indexed. Any thoughts would be of great help.

Comment: I see 2 options: 1. the simplest imho, which you already seem to refer to (?), would be to have a year field per document. And have a once-a-year-job remove/reindex documents based on a particular year. 2. Have a multicore setup, in which each core would contain a year.  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin . hth

Comment: Of course having multiple cores, you need to use distributed search if you want to search over all (or some subset) of the year-cores at once. See: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch. Multicore opens up a lot of optimization possibilities, e.g: based on search-distribution it might be beneficial to have recent years running on SSD and years further back run on normal drives, etc.

Comment: Can the moving of indexes to respective cores be done automatically by SOLR? By the documentation I understood that I need to manually move the indexes to cores but thats not what we intend to do here. When the data gets indexed by SOLR, i want SOLR to automatically place the indexes in appropriate index folders based on the created date and thats how the index would be partitioned. Is there a way to do this in SOLR?